# Pulling real-time data using ESPN API

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working on a way to pull real-time data into a tkinter GUI and have gotten it to the point I want for basketball but it seems that the layout and way to pull data using the ESPN API is different for golf. I know that I have to first find the player's id using the first URL in the code below, but after that I am having trouble pulling and posting data for only that one athlete. If someone could show me an example of how to just pull the score for one particular player given an ID for the current day or how many holes they have played so far, that would be great. I am fairly new to Python so any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import requests
import time

def get_data(query):

    url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/search?region=us&lang=en&query={}&limit=5&mode=prefix&type=player'.format(query)

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    id_ = data['items'][0]['id']
    name = data['items'][0]['displayName']

    url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/golf/leaderboard?league=pga'
    r = requests.get(url)

    data = r.json()

    DailyScore = data['competition']['']['']

    return (id_,name,DailyScore)

# --- main ---

query = 'Rickie'

print('id:', id_)
print('name:',name)
print('Daily Score:',DailyScore)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON returned by the second request contains 1 key ("events"), which is a list containing 1 item with data for the "Workday Charity Open". Subsequently this data contains a key "competitions", which is a list containing 1 item with all the details of the event. Therefore to traverse through the JSON to access competitor data for this event, you need to do something like:

```
competitors = data["events"][0]["competitions"][0]["competitors"]
```

And then to access the data for the specific player id:

```
player_data = [i for i in competitors if i["id"] == id_][0]
```

Comment: It seems like when I enter this into the code, I am not getting anything to print. How would I make it so I could print the displayValue under either the score or linescores part of the API? Sorry, I may just not be understanding what you previously said.

Comment: You'll need to call those keys in the dictionary. I'm going to put that below, but accept Toby's solution as it's correct

Comment: Thanks @chitown88 - yes I didn't go the final step of pulling the specific keys from the player data.

Answer (score 0):

So in that `player_data` data (see image below for visual), you'll need to go to the keys `['score']['displayValue']`. The same for `linescores`. HOWEVER, notice `linescores` is a list, so I suspect each day, they'll append the latest score on, so for that, you'd need to call the last item in the list. I put that in there too, but commented it out

[image]

```
import requests

def get_data(query):

    url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/search?region=us&lang=en&query={}&limit=5&mode=prefix&type=player'.format(query)

    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    id_ = data['items'][0]['id']
    name = data['items'][0]['displayName']

    url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/golf/leaderboard?league=pga'
    r = requests.get(url)

    data = r.json()

    competitors = data["events"][0]["competitions"][0]["competitors"]
    player_data = [i for i in competitors if i["id"] == id_][0]
    
    DailyScore = player_data['score']['displayValue']
    #DailyScore = player_data['linescores'][-1]['displayValue']

    return (id_,name,DailyScore)

# --- main ---

query = 'Rickie'

id_, name, DailyScore = get_data(query)

print('id:', id_)
print('name:',name)
print('Daily Score:',DailyScore)
```

**Output:**

```
id: 3702
name: Rickie Fowler
Daily Score: +9
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helped me visualize the data inside the API. How did you load it into spyder like that? I have it downloaded but being able to use this for other APIs in the future would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On the right side (if it’s the default layout), there should be a tab called variable window, or variable display, or variable explore (something like that, can’t remember exactly the name, but it “variable ”. Then once something is stored, you can double click around and explore its contents. Ya it really helped me understand json structures when I first was learning.

Comment: I'm seeing the end results on the right hand side in the variable explorer but I can't seem to figure out how to follow the path to that end point like you did in your example below.

Comment: Double click to “open” each part